# Delphi 2010 - generate http-request and redirecting to web browser

Tags: delphi, web

I need to do this in Delphi 2010. I do not use .net

This code is in Java:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
GetMethod method = new GetMethod();
method = new GetMethod("https://www.xxxxx.xx/portal/ILlogin?username=XXXXXX&password=XXXXXXXX&skin=yyyyyyyyyy&portal=GG");
method.setFollowRedirects(false);
int rc = client.executeMethod(method);
Header locationHeader = method.getResponseHeader("location");
if(locationHeader != null) {
  tokenURL = locationHeader.getValue();
}
```

It is a http request which generates a redirect to webreader.

How do I code this in Delphi 2010.

Answer (score 3):

Delphi ships with Indy pre-installed.  You can use Indy's TIdHTTP component, eg:

```
client := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
try
  client.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(client);
  TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(client.IOHandler).SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;

  client.HandleRedirects := False; 
  client.Get('https://www.xxxxx.xx/portal/ILlogin?username=XXXXXX&password=XXXXXXXX&skin=yyyyyyyyyy&portal=GG', [300, 301, 302, 303, 305, 306, 307]);

  if client.Response.Location <> '' then
    tokenURL := client.Response.Location;
finally
  client.Free;
end;
```